# MongoDB: Searching a text field using mathematical operators

Tags: string, mongodb, search, operators

I have documents in a MongoDB as below -

```
[
{
    "_id": "17tegruebfjt73efdci342132",
    "name": "Test User1",
    "obj":  "health=8,type=warrior",
},
{
    "_id": "wefewfefh32j3h42kvci342132",
    "name": "Test User2",
    "obj":  "health=6,type=magician",
}
.
.
]
```

I want to run a query say `health>6` and it should return the `"Test User1"` entry. The `obj` key is indexed as a text field so I can do `{$text:{$search:"health=8"}}` to get an exact match but I am trying to incorporate mathematical operators into the search.

I am aware of the `$gt` and `$lt` operators, however, it cannot be used in this case as `health` is not a key of the document. The easiest way out is to make `health` a key of the document for sure, but I cannot change the document structure due to certain constraints.

Is there anyway this can be achieved? I am aware that mongo supports running javascript code, not sure if that can help in this case.

Comment: You can try transforming the data in an aggregation query, like extracting the appropriate sub-strings and match/search thru them (since you had already mentioned changing the data design is not an option). But, this wont be a very efficient search, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JavaScript is one way of doing what you want. Below is a `find` that uses the index on `obj` by finding documents that have `health=` text followed by an integer (if you want, you can anchor that with `^` in the regex).

It then uses a JavaScript function to parse out the actual integer after substringing your way past the `health=` part, doing a `parseInt` to get the int, and then the comparison operator/value you mentioned in the question.

```
db.collection.find({
    // use the index on obj to potentially speed up the query
    "obj":/health=\d+/,
    // now apply a function to narrow down and do the math
    $where: function() {
        var i = this.obj.indexOf("health=") + 7;
        var s = this.obj.substring(i);
        var m = s.match(/\d+/);
        
        if (m)
            return parseInt(m[0]) > 6;       
        return false;
    }
})
```

You can of course tweak it to your heart's content to use other operators.

> NOTE: I'm using the JavaScript regex capability, which may not be supported by MongoDB. I used **Mongo-Shell r4.2.6** where it ***is*** supported. If that's the case, in the JavaScript, you will have to extract the integer out a different way.

I provided a [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EORijpl4lzc) to try it out in if you want to tweak it, but you'll get

```
Invalid query:

Line 3: Javascript regex are not supported. Use "$regex" instead
```

until you change it to account for the regex issue noted above. Still, if you're using the latest and greatest, this shouldn't be a limitation.

**Performance**

> Disclaimer: This analysis is *not* rigorous.

I ran two queries against a small collection (a bigger one could possibly have resulted in different results) with Explain Plan in MongoDB Compass. The first query is the one above; the second is the same query, but with the `obj` filter removed.

[image]

and

[image]

As you can see the plans are different. The number of documents examined is fewer for the first query, and the first query uses the index.

The execution times are meaningless because the collection is small. The results do seem to square with the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), but the documentation seems a little at odds with itself. Here are two excerpts

> Use the `$where` operator to pass either a string containing a JavaScript expression or a full JavaScript function to the query system. The `$where` provides greater flexibility, but requires that the database processes the JavaScript expression or function for *each* document in the collection.

and

> Using normal non-`$where` query statements provides the following performance advantages:
>
> - MongoDB will evaluate non-`$where` components of query before `$where` statements. If the non-`$where` statements match no documents, MongoDB will not perform any query evaluation using `$where`.
> - The non-`$where` query statements may use an index.

I'm not totally sure what to make of this, TBH. As a general solution it might be useful because it seems you could generate queries that can handle all of your operators.

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to know the performance impact of using javascript directly as you suggested? I've read that using JavaScript forces the query to run on all documents (instead of the index).

Comment: @m0bi5, sure. I updated the answer. It was interesting taking a longer look...

Comment: Yeah the "..JavaScript expression or function for each document in the collection.." in the documentation was what confused me. But it doesn't seem to be the case. Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible in `$text` search index, but you can transform your object conditions to an array of objects using an aggregation query,

- `$split` to split `obj` by "," and it will return an array
- `$map` to iterate loop of the above split result array
- `$split` to split current condition by "=" and it will return an array
- `$let` to declare the variable `cond` to store the result of the above split result
- `$first` to return the first element from the above split result in `k` as a key of condition
- `$last` to return the last element from the above split result in `v` as a value of the condition
- now we have ready an array of objects of string conditions:

```
  "objTransform": [
    { "k": "health", "v": "9" },
    { "k": "type", "v": "warrior" }
  ]
```

- `$match` condition for key and value to match in the same object using `$elemMatch`
- `$unset` to remove transform array `objTransform`, because it's not needed

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      objTransform: {
        $map: {
          input: { $split: ["$obj", ","] },
          in: {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                cond: { $split: ["$$this", "="] }
              },
              in: {
                k: { $first: "$$cond" },
                v: { $last: "$$cond" }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      objTransform: {
        $elemMatch: {
          k: "health",
          v: { $gt: "8" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unset: "objTransform" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tJW33lRqLyp)

---

The second upgraded version of the above aggregation query to do less operation in condition transformation if it's possible to manage in your client-side,

- `$split` to split `obj` by "," and it will return an array
- `$map` to iterate loop of the above split result array
- `$split` to split current condition by "=" and it will return an array
- now we have ready a nested array of string conditions:

```
  "objTransform": [
    ["type", "warrior"],
    ["health", "9"]
  ]
```

- `$match` condition for key and value to match in the array element using `$elemMatch`, "0" to match the first position of the array and "1" to match the second position of the array
- `$unset` to remove transform array `objTransform`, because it's not needed

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      objTransform: {
        $map: {
          input: { $split: ["$obj", ","] },
          in: { $split: ["$$this", "="] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      objTransform: {
        $elemMatch: {
          "0": "health",
          "1": { $gt: "8" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unset: "objTransform" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m1i3P-67g6d)